# Spring MVC POST request with dto that contains multipart files and other dtos

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, multipartfile

I have a DTO that contains other DTOs and a list of multipart files. I am trying to process that DTO but I can't seem to be able to read the requst.

```
class TeacherDTO {
   private SpecializationDto specializationDto;
   private List<MultipartFile> files;
}

@PostMapping(consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE},
            produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
public ResponseEntity<Object> saveNewTeacher(@ModelAttribute @Valid TeacherDTO teacherDto){

//process request

}
```

When creating an example request from Swagger UI, I get the following exception:

```
type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'SpecializationDto' for property 'specializationDto': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

If I put @RequestBody instead of @ModelAttribute then I get

```
Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryVEgYwEbpl1bAOjAs;charset=UTF-8' not supported]
```

Swagger dependencies:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
   <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
   <version>1.5.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
   <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-data-rest</artifactId>
   <version>1.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

OpenAPI3.0 config:

```
@Configuration
public class OpenApi30Config {

  private final String moduleName;
  private final String apiVersion;

  public OpenApi30Config(
      @Value("${spring.application.name}") String moduleName,
      @Value("${api.version}") String apiVersion) {
    this.moduleName = moduleName;
    this.apiVersion = apiVersion;
  }

  @Bean
  public OpenAPI customOpenAPI() {
    final var securitySchemeName = "bearerAuth";
    final var apiTitle = String.format("%s API", StringUtils.capitalize(moduleName));
    return new OpenAPI()
        .addSecurityItem(new SecurityRequirement().addList(securitySchemeName))
        .components(
            new Components()
                .addSecuritySchemes(securitySchemeName,
                    new SecurityScheme()
                        .name(securitySchemeName)
                        .type(SecurityScheme.Type.HTTP)
                        .scheme("bearer")
                        .bearerFormat("JWT")
                )
        )
        .info(new Info().title(apiTitle).version(apiVersion));
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you facing this problem only from the swagger client?

Comment: Yes, I want to get it working with the swagger UI

Comment: You need to provide more details including swagger version etc otherwise it would be hard to depict the issue if any.

Comment: @harry updated with open api configuration. I use Open API 3.0

Comment: You're mixing two things here. Posting a JSON object and posting multipart data. I would recommend not doing this. Post only multipart data to some endpoint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with how the springdoc-openapi-ui builds the form-data request. I was able to reproduce this and noticed that it sends a multipart-request like (intercepted through browser's dev-tools):

```
-----------------------------207598777410513073071314493349
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="specializationDto"\r\n\r\n{\r\n  "something": "someValue"\r\n}


-----------------------------207598777410513073071314493349
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"; filename="somefile.txt"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

<content>

-----------------------------207598777410513073071314493349
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"; filename="somefile.txt"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

<content>
```

With that payload Spring is not able to deserialize the `specializationDto`, resulting in the "no matching editors or conversion strategy found" exception that you've observed. However, if you send the request through postman or curl with (note the dot-notation for the specializationDto object)

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/upload' \
--form 'files=@"/path/to/somefile"' \
--form 'files=@"/path/to/somefile"' \
--form 'specializationDto.something="someValue"'
```

then Spring is able to parse it correctly. Here's my rest-mapping that will log the following as expected:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST, 
                    consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
    public void upload(@ModelAttribute TeacherDto requestDto) {
        System.out.println(requestDto);
    }


// logs:
TeacherDto(specializationDto=SpecializationDto(something=someValue), files=[org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile@78186ea6, org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile@461c9cbc])
```

I suggest you open a bug on their github [page](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues).

EDIT:

After OP opened a github ticket, here's part of the author's feedback:

> [...] With spring, you can use @RequestPart spring annotation to describe
> the different parts, with the related encoding media type. Note that
> there is a limitation with the current swagger-ui implementation as
> the encoding attribute is not respected on the request.[...]

They also provided a possible workaround, which looks like this:

```
@PostMapping(consumes =  MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Object> saveNewTeacher( @RequestPart(value = "specializationDto") @Parameter(schema =@Schema(type = "string", format = "binary"))  final SpecializationDto specializationDto,
        @RequestPart(value = "files")  final List<MultipartFile> files){
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this response. I've created a bug on their github repo and their reply is here. Can you please edit your response with their response so I can approve your message as the correct answer, given the fact that you pushed it to the right direction?

https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/1416

Comment: Done :) Nice to hear that there's at least a workaround.